# Rating Bar Customization in Android

Tags: android, ratingbar

The rating bar which we are giving should be shown,here i have given the value rating in float ,but its  showing completely full 5 star rating,please clarify with me that while the service is giving the value of rating from the server,that value must be shown in app.How to create that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a post](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/) that will teach how to customize your `RatingBar`.

Basically you have to create a custom style and create selector states, and set this style to your `RatingBar`.

Comment: how cn i implement that

Comment: have you read the post!?